# PhoneGap App stopped loading to Apple Test Flight with Icon Missing Error. Worked OK until a month or two ago

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, testflight

Our latest build of a `PhoneGap` application for `iOS` and `Android`, was built OK on the `ADOBE PhoneGap` build site.

When we attempt to load it from an `Apple MAC` onto the Apple Test Flight system, we get this error:

> "Missing App Icon..."

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngt5n.png)
This relates to the App Store Icon 1024x1024

We are now on `version 24` of the App - so 23 previous versions built and loaded OK.

We have set up all the necessary Apple IDs etc. (and all has been working fine) although in the past we used to get a WARNING about the missing Icon, now the Load just stops.

We have contacted Apple Support who suggested rebuilding and trying again. Not made any difference...

I have found a number of articles that suggest we needed to update our CONFIG.XML file, with details of the icon with size 1024x1024, and also to use PhoneGap CLI 7.1.0. No success.

here is the CONFIG file (or at least the relevant bits)

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.cognect.mobile" version="1.0.24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="phone-gap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />
    
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<and a whole load more plugins...>
    
<platform name="ios">
<icon platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="1024" height="1024" />                
<icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
<icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
<and a whole load more icons....>        

<splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />        
<splash height="768" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
<splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
<splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />

</platform>
```